# Encoded List<dynamic> cannot be mapped to TableRow flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show list of maps in the `TableRow`. The json `listMap` has the following format without the quotes around the keys and key values:

```
[
  {
    "item1": "value1",

  },
  {
    "item2": "value2",

  },
  {
    "item3": "value3",

  },

]
```

I am grabbing this list of objects and the variable listMap contains this format json without quotes.

```
  Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Table(
            columnWidths: const {
              0: FixedColumnWidth(50),
              1: FlexColumnWidth(),
            },
            children: (widget.listMap)
                .map((object) {
              return TableRow(children: [
                Container(
                    color: (widget.listMap)
                                    .indexOf(object) %
                                2 ==
                            0
                        ? const Color(0xFF161616)
                        : Colors.grey[800],
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Text(
                      object['item1'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )),
              ]);
            }).toList(),
            border: TableBorder.all(
                width: 1, color: Color(0xFF161616)),
          ),
        ),
      ))
```

I get the error:  'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'
`.  This is because` TableRow` does not recognize the json keys and values without quotes.

How can i resolve this issue?

**Edit**

So edited the json with quotes because people found it confusing why used the json keys and values without quotes, but that is the format i get from the variable `widget.listMap`

`widget.listMap` is the json but without the quotes around the keys and values which is why i get the error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<TableRow>'` 
**Edit**

This the code that grabs the json object:

```
class TestData {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getTestData() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test_json/test_json1.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Edit**
Code below shows that `listMap` is passed from another widget and then i make it a `List`

```
class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List listMap;
  const AppView({Key? key, required this.listMap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppBaseState createState() => _AppBaseState();
}
```

Comment: but why the data format is wrong in the first place?

Comment: Because I get error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<TableRow>'
` Its not wrong but i don't know how use that format for `TableRow`

Comment: the format of map data is wrong !!!!!

Comment: The format is actually in quotes but when debugprint() it it show it without quotes and that is where it goes wrong

Comment: That is the reason why i showed the json format like that because that what i get

Comment: I see, then you should have told me earlier. In the console, output quotes are not printed but that doesn't mean you have to reencode the map again because you thought based on the console output !!

Comment: don't re-encode the listMap variable and it should work fine.

Comment: That is the thing, when i remove re-encode i get the error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<TableRow>'
`

Comment: When i use a dummy json like `[{ "item1" : "value1"
}]` it works but it doesn't work when i use listMap which is the format without the quotes

Comment: just encode the map-values... not the whole list ...

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: can you show the code that creates your list?

Comment: I added now the code that grabs the json and mapps it in the last edit from OP

Comment: ok... this is the map... can you also show the code where you put it into a list?

Comment: `class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List listMap;
  const AppView({Key? key, required this.listMap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppBaseState createState() => _AppBaseState();
}`

Comment: In the stateful widget above i set `listMap` as `List` which is passed from another stateful widget

Comment: I also added the code in OP now

Comment: Thank you...it's still a bit confusing to me... I tried your code (you can see the full code as answer) and there was no error... I think there is somewhere a wrong data-type-declaration inyour code and this may lead to the error... maybe it helps to compare your code with mine... I hope so :)

Comment: Thank but for me it doesn't work because i actually use another json object which contains the list of objects

Comment: can you show me the json?

Comment: I posted another question with the same problem and the json : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647735/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listtablerow-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Is your `listMap` a Map or a String?

If it's a **Map**, for example something like this:

```
final listMap = [
  {'item1': 'value1'},
  {'item2': 'value2'},
  {'item3': 'value3'},
];
```

Then you can use it in the widget by mapping that Map and using `object` to get an `index` from `listMap`.

```
children: listMap.map((object) {
  final index = listMap.indexOf(object);
  return TableRow(
    children: [
      Container(
        color: index % 2 == 0 ? const Color(0xFF161616) : Colors.grey[800],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(
          object['item$index'].toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}).toList(),
```

If it's a **String**, for example:

```
final listJsonString = "[{\"item0\":\"value1\"},{\"item1\":\"value2\"},{\"item2\":\"value3\"}]";
```

Then you have to decode it from the JSON first:

```
final parsedListJson = jsonDecode(listJsonString);
final listMap = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(parsedListJson.map((i) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(i)));
```

Comment: The format of the json i get is the first one but `listMap` is in the format from OP because i grab it from another widget

Comment: I get the map with keys and values without quotes which is why i get the error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<TableRow>'
`

Comment: So neither options work

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and had no errors:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 List<Map<String,dynamic>> myListMap=[];

  void loadJson() async {
    myListMap= [await TestData().getTestData()];
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadJson();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  MyHomePage(listMap: myListMap),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String,dynamic>> listMap;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.listMap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Table(
              columnWidths: const {
                0: FixedColumnWidth(50),
                1: FlexColumnWidth(),
              },
              children: (widget.listMap)
                  .map((object) {
                return TableRow(children: [
                  Container(
                      color: (widget.listMap)
                          .indexOf(object) %
                          2 ==
                          0
                          ? const Color(0xFF161616)
                          : Colors.grey[800],
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Text(
                        object['item1'].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                ]);
              }).toList(),
              border: TableBorder.all(
                  width: 1, color: Color(0xFF161616)),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}


class TestData {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getTestData() async {
    String jsonData =
    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test_json1.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }
}
```